# Mp4 Flash Videos Cannot be played in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash, flash-player, html5

Some flash videos won't play in Chrome, while they play perfectly in other browsers. The player will load, but instead of showing a preview of the video, it shows me :" Video Not Found " and it gives me a pop-out for Internet Download manager to download an MP4 File !!

I have The latest Flash Player Installed in Windows 7 Ultimate in a 64-bit machine I have All the plugins Enabled and all The Extensions disabled.

Is there some kind of a solution for This Issue ?

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/108086?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

That's because IDM takes control of downloading `mp4` extension file  from chrome.

---

**Solution**

**Method 1:**
1.Open up IDM, click **`Options`**
[image]
2.In `File types` tab, just delete the **MP4** extension, the below picture shown means IDM will capture the MP4 files, but to play it in Browser, just delete MP4 and click OK. ***You may have to restart Chrome.*** Now you can play videos directly in chrome as it should.
[image]

**Method 2:**
Type `chrome://plugins/` in address bar. You can see IDM plugin there, now disable it. Now you can play your videos in chrome.
[image]

Another way is to disintegrate IDM from Chrome by unchecking the `Google Chrome` check box in General tab of IDM's Options(configuration) dialog box as seen below.
[image]

Comment: no, It's not 
I found That the problem is that there is a Conflict between Two Flash Plugins, one that it comes originally installed in Chrome, and The Other One That I installed after. 
So, That's just it, now every thing is Working fine and smooth